# Uploading multiple photos and storing in the database with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I've been following a tutorial [here](http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/) on how to attach multiple files to a Laravel Item but I keep running into an error with the saving of the files to the table.

`Call to a member function store() on array`

The Job saves perfectly fine to my database but that error happens to my attempt at saving the files.

I seem to be getting this error any time I try to use the store method on files and I'd love any insight into this.

JobController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use App\Job;
Use App\Brand;
Use App\JobType;
use App\JobFile;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ...

        $job = Job::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'brand_id' => $request->brand_id,
            'job_type_id' => $request->job_type_id
        ]);

        foreach ($request->files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->store('job-files');
            JobFile::create([
                'job_id' => $job->id,
                'filename' => $filename
            ]);
        }

        return redirect('/jobs');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
<form action="/jobs/create" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">File Upload(s)</label>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this one: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-multiple-files-images-upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get first the array of all files after than you can make the foreach.

```
if($request->hasFile('files')) {
    $files = $request->file('files');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filename = $file->store('job-files');
        JobFile::create([
            'job_id'   => $job->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm once I took out that $cms variable. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, my mistak. I tested it and forgotten to remove it.